# Why is my html being overwritten when I specify a css classname for a video element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an icon that I want to display on a video (with the i tag in the code below). However, when I add a css classname to the video tag (to perform a transform to mirror the video), the icon no longer displays. In addition, in the code, neither the icon nor the stuff in the next div are being displayed when I add the video classname. I want be able to both display the icon and have the classname for the video tag.

I'm aware that adding !important to the css classes will increase their specificity score, but from what I have read, that's not the best way to solve this problem.

```
<i className="iconClass" />
<div className="class2">{var}</div>
<video className="mirror" ref={node => this.video = node}
    autoPlay={true}
    controls={false}
    playsInline={true}
    muted={true}
/>
```

I want to see the video displayed with both the var from the div tag and the icon from the i tag displayed.

Comment: There's no reason why the icon should be outright removed by simply adding a className to the video. Are you *sure* it's being removed? As in, does it show up in the DOM? It's quite possible that, like you say, it's either simply being hidden by other CSS or that the CSS you wrote is being overridden by specificity. Do you see the element show up in F12, and if so, are there are rules overwriting it?

Comment: Might be a stupid question since I am not familiar with JSX ?   However, don't you need a closing tag for an 'i" element rather than self-closing it ?  It does seem to make a difference.

Comment: When I hover over the lines of css for the icon and the div tag, I see those areas highlighted on the page. One thing I should add is that the class for the video is for mirroring the video, so it does a transform. Maybe this is relevant.

Comment: How come there is a parenthesis here? className={"iconClass")}  it doesn't have another to match

Comment: Fixed the parenthesis/braces

Comment: Did that fix your problem? Along with the word className..?  That, along with the curly braces would only be valid with some framework.. which I'm guessing you're not using

Comment: No I only messed up the braces when typing the code here. changing classname to class didn't help. I think the css/html tags are being overwritten by the mirroring transform, but I'm not sure how to fix/debug it.

Comment: Your "i" tag isn't doing anything btw.. in order for it to make something italic or affect another element, it needs to wrap the element.. <i>something</i>

Comment: If you think the css is the problem, post the css that corresponds to the code along with it

Comment: To debug you can just right click and inspect element.. you can pause the javascript or change the css to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

First,`className` is not a valid html tag attribute, it is a property of a dom object in javascript. What you should use is:

```
<i class="iconClass" />
```

Also, the `i` and `video`tags both need to be closed:

```
<i class="iconClass"></i>
<video class="videoClass" ...></video>
```

Only ***empty elements*** can be closed at the end of the opening tag.
The ***empty elements*** in HTML are as follows:

```
<area>
<base>
<br>
<col>
<embed>
<hr>
<img>
<input>
<keygen>(HTML 5.2 Draft removed)
<link>
<meta>
<param>
<source>
<track>
<wbr>
```

Comment: The tags are closed. You can see the /> at the end of each of them.